# Что означают цвета в composer?

Tags: php, composer

Есть небольшая выдержка с англоязычного сайта:

> `Green: The package is up to date!`
>
> `Yellow: There's a new version, but`
> `possibly with BC break, there may be some work to install the new`
> `version`
>
> `Red: There should be no BC break (semver), you should upgrade`
> `the package.`

Что такое BC break? Обратная совместимость? Жёлтые это значит что при обновлении пакета могут возникнуть проблемы, а красные что точно возникнут?

Comment: «красные что точно возникнут» — всё с точностью до наоборот: «There should be **NO** BC break»

Comment: @andreymal т.е. пакеты отмеченные красным можно обновлять в первую очередь без опаски?

Comment: так и написано _"you should upgrade the package."_

Comment: @teran это я понял что "вы должны обновить пакет" но не создаст ли это обновление проблем

Comment: ну дак процитировали выше ведь, "НЕ должно быть проблем с обратной совместимостью"

Answer (score 2):

**Зеленый**: У пакета уже последняя версия!

**Желтый**: У пакета есть новая версия, но есть вероятность возникновения проблем, связанных с обратной совместимостью. Может потребоваться некоторая работа, чтобы успешно его установить.

**Красный**: Полагаясь на номер версии ([semver](https://semver.org/)) пакета, проблем, с обратной совместимостью, быть не должно. Обновите пакет.